# store only object.value into set() based on object.differentValue === static value

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out the best way to do this without hitting a bad bigO. Basically I have a value identifier `name` and I want to only grab the unique value in the object `object.id` based upon if the `object.name === name`, so the `Set()` will contain the id's only related to the condition where name is found.

Example...

```
const uniqueIds = new Set();
const name = "billy";
const objects = [
    {id: 1, name: "billy"},
    {id: 2, name: "billy"},
    {id: 3, name: "jack"},
    {id: 4, name: "kevin"},
]
```

What is the best way for instantiating uniqueIds with [1,2]?

Do I really have to use a `filter()` into a new array, and then use `map()` to then use `uniqueIds.add(id)`?

Or is there a better way to do this using a shortcut of something like `insert ids into uniqueIds where objects.name === name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `Set` for getting unique ids

```js
const name = "billy";
const objects = [
    {id: 1, name: "billy"},
    {id: 2, name: "billy"},
    {id: 2, name: "billy"},
    {id: 3, name: "jack"},
    {id: 4, name: "kevin"},
]

const uniqueIds = objects.reduce((result, obj)=>{
  if(obj.name === name) result.add(obj.id)
  return result
}, new Set())

console.log(Array.from(new Set(uniqueIds)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that it helped @FiddleFreak :)